Dart pass by reference or pass by value
I am working on a Dart project and found it confusing about the value assignment for Dart. Before this, I did some research on google which it tells me that the value assignment for Dart is pass by value instead of pass by reference. So, I did a simple prototype to test and the results was quite different on different data types, can anyone here help to explain this?
Prototype code:
  var num1 = 12;
  var num2 = 24;
  var num3 = num1;
  print('before: $num3');
  num1 = 99;
  print('after: ${num3}');
  print('');
  
  
  List<Person> A1 = [Person('Lucas', 12), Person('Amanda', 12), Person('Zespri', 12)];
  List<Person> A2 = A1;
  for (var S in A2) {print('before: ${S.name}');}
  print('');
  A1[1].name = 'Bob';
  for (var S in A2) {print('after: ${S.name}');}

Results:
before: 12
after: 12

before: Lucas
before: Amanda
before: Zespri

after: Lucas
after: Bob
after: Zespri


In Dart, "everything is an object" (even null), and so "passing" is always "pass by reference".
At least that's how one can think about it, for "atomic values"/"primitive data types"/"things which are not graphs of other things"/"immutable objects", the compiler will do optimizations, copying the underlying "bytes representing the value" instead of passing pointers to memory locations which have to be looked up at considerable cost, but that's really one level down. Note that the moniker "primitive data type" doesn't even appear in the language specification.
That being said, we have no passing going here, just various variables referencing the same object.
Let me add an image...
For the situation with the "primitive data types":

num1 references 12
num2 references 24
num3 references whatever num1 referenced, which is 12

and the state is changed so that

num1 references 99


And for the case of the complex data structure, we have this.
As you can see we just change data somewhere in the graph of objects referenced by two different variable. So obviously, if you walk through the graph via A1 or via A2, you will see the same changes:


No.  Pass-by-reference means that the a function can reassign variables passed by the caller.  Dart is not pass-by-reference.  Dart is pass-by-sharing.

@jamesdlin Ok, got it.

Primitive Types (int, double, bool, etc.)  are pased by value while Objects (Lists, Maps, custom classes, etc.) are passed by reference

No, Dart does not have primitive types. All types are objects. int, double, bool, etc. are just immutable. Dart is not pass-by-reference.
